# Seems xpath translate not working as expected in java8

Tags: java, xpath, case-insensitive

I searched a lot to find the exact equivalent but not able to find. The question over here is the translate method of java8- javax.xml.xpath.* is not giving the expected output.

example-

Actual-

```
XPathExpression xpathitemtype = xpath.compile("//*[@type=\"" + xpathType + "\"]/ancestor::itemtype");
final NodeList itemType = (NodeList) xpathitemtype.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

using translate-

```
XPathExpression xpathitemtype = xpath.compile("//*[translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='" + xpathType.toLowerCase() + "']/ancestor::itemtype");
final NodeList itemType = (NodeList) xpathitemtype.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Now i used translate because I like to get the itemType irrespective of the case in the given xml document-

example if value is-
exportMedia or ExportMedia or EXportMEdia any case just return the output.

Now in the above both example returns the same output it seems translate is not working in my case

```
 <itemtype code="RemoveCatalogVersionJob">
 <attribute qualifier="catalogVersion" type="CatalogVersion">
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="removedItems" type="ExportMEdia">
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="notRemovedItems" type="exportMedia">
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
 </itemtype>
```

Now I want the item value if it is any cases of exportMedia

Answer (score 0):

Your code works properly as well as XPath is evaluated properly. The problem is that XPath expression contains "ancestor::itemtype" in the end and both of matched "attribute" elements have only one ancestor with name "itemtype".

If you'll change your code for a test...

```
    XPathExpression xpathItemType = xpath.compile("//*[translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='" + xpathType.toLowerCase() + "']/@qualifier");
    final NodeList itemType = (NodeList) xpathItemType.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for(int i = 0; i < itemType.getLength(); i ++) {
        System.out.println(itemType.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```

... the output will be

```
removedItems
notRemovedItems
```

... showing, that both "ExportMEdia" and "exportMedia" matched your expression.

Alternatively you can change your input XML to something like this (just an example without knowing the real scheme):

```
<items>
    <itemtype code="RemoveCatalogVersionJob">
        <attribute qualifier="notRemovedItems" type="exportMedia">
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
    </itemtype>
    <itemtype code="RemoveCatalogVersionJob1">
        <attribute qualifier="removedItems" type="ExportMEdia">
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
    </itemtype>
</items>
```

Your code will match both itemtype with code="RemoveCatalogVersionJob" with code="RemoveCatalogVersionJob1".